# How do i set the read more link?

Tags: links

I read the others on the site and i didnt find a working solution. I am using the 20-11 theme and i tried using `<--more-->` (in visual and html) with no luck, using excerpts and whatever i could find. Nothing work

I am viewing the page from the root/homepage. How do i make the read more link with just a paragraph or two of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `<!--more-->`

or try the 4th button from the right in the visual editor;

or try the 'more' button in the html editor.

> I am viewing the page

does that mean you are trying to get a 'read-more' in a static page?